# Tensorflow installation error in keras package: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow

Tags: python, r, keras, rstudio

I'm trying to install keras and tensorflow using the `install_keras()` command in R_Studio. Keras installs, however Tensorflow installation seems to be aborting with:

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for tensorflow

Error message displayed:

[image: Figure 1]

Comment: Seems TF is not available for your specific setup. More information about your platform will be required.